# Python Unencode unicode html hexadecimal

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, html-parsing, ascii

Suppose I have strings with lots of stuff like

```
&#x00e2;&#x0080;&#x009c;words words words
```

Is there a way to convert these through python directly into the characters they represent?

I tried

```
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print h.unescape(x)
```

but got this error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

I also tried

```
print h.unescape(x).encode(utf-8)
```

but it encodes

`&#x00e2;&#x0080;&#x009c;` as `â`

when it should be a quote

Comment: what makes you think `&#x00e2;&#x0080;&#x009c;` should be a comma? what webpage is this coming from? to convert them to the characters they represent `h.unescape(x)`  does that ... but when you try and print it there are problems ... try looking at its repr

Comment: i said quote not comma. from the context it is clear it is a quote because these appear at the beginning and end of a string that should have quotes. also this page shows this in the "As a string of HTML entities:" part http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?characters=%E2%80%9C

Comment: my mistake ... ok that gives me more to work with hold on

Comment: Are you generating the NCR escapes, or are they coming form external source? If from an external source are they present in the external source? AS others have indicated You have a quotation mark, where the bytes are being escape rather than the character being escape. There is a miss-encoding in the pipeline somewhere. The first step is to identify where in the pipeline this error is occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#x00e2;&#x0080;&#x009c;` form a *UTF-8 byte sequence*, for the [U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+201c) character. Something is majorly mucked up there. The correct encoding would have been `&ldquo;`.

You *can* use the HTML parser to unescape this, but you'll need to repair the resulting [Mochibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> x = '&#x00e2;&#x0080;&#x009c;'
>>> h.unescape(x)
u'\xe2\x80\x9c'
>>> h.unescape(x).encode('latin1')
'\xe2\x80\x9c'
>>> h.unescape(x).encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'\u201c'
>>> print h.unescape(x).encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
“
```

If *printing* still gives you a UnicodeEncodeError, then your terminal or console is incorrectly configured and Python is inadventently encoding to ASCII.

Comment: thank you this was what i was looking for. i am parsing through some web crawler stuff that is going through some messed up pages. the last line worked in terminal though not in sublime text so you're right i need to configure that

Comment: Yes, the SublimeText console is not communicating the codec it uses, IIRC.

Comment: ahh much better than my method of getting it out of a unicode string +1 nice work

Comment: That's not a valid use of `&#` entities. Those are supposed to be unicode codepoints, so the correct representation would have been `&#x201c;`. (&ldquo; is also ok in HTML, but you can always use the `&#x` form even if you're not generating HTML.)

Comment: @rici: yup, you can even just include the literal character and encode the document properly to, say, UTF-8. I just picked `&ldquo;` as it is actually defined.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you cannot decode unicode properly ... you need to convert it away from unicode to just utf8

```
x="&#x00e2;&#x0080;&#x009c;words words words"
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
msg=h.unescape(x) #this converts it to unicode string ..
downcast = "".join(chr(ord(c)&0xff) for c in msg) #convert it to normal string (python2)
print downcast.decode("utf8")
```

there may be a better way to do this in the HTMLParser library ...

Comment: Because it is a UTF-8 encoded U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK codepoint. It is a Mochibake.